# Any submodule U of V such that the module V/U is completely reducible must contain the radical?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

Want to prove:
Given an $R$-Module $V$ and $rad(V)$ which I define to be the intersection of all maximal submodules of $V$. I want to show that if, for some submodule $U$ of $V$, we have $V/U$ completely reducible, then $U$ must contain $Rad(V)$.

$\\$
I had some ideas: Namely if $V/U$ is completely reducible then we can write it as the direct sum of irreducible modules $U_{1}/V\oplus U_{2}/V\oplus\cdots\oplus U_{k}/V$. Then perhaps one can show that $U$ each of $U_{1}$$+...+$$U_{i-1}$$+U_{i+1}$$+... +U_{k}$ is maximal then work with that?

$\\$
Or perhaps one could define an injection from $V/Rad(V)$ to $V/U$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your definition of (completely) reduced module?

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ runs all maximal modules of $V$, so $\displaystyle \bigcap_M M= Rad (V)$. Then $(M+U)/U$ is maximal in $V/U$. It is easy to prove that 
$$
(\bigcap_M M +U)/U \subseteq \bigcap_M \left( (M +U)/U \right).
$$
The left-hand side is $(Rad (V)+U)/U$, the right-hand side is $0$ since  $Rad (V/U)=0$. Hence $Rad (V)\subseteq U$.

Comment: Could you please explain your first line? What do you mean by "let M runs all Maximal modules..." and why is it clear that (M+U)/U is maximal in V/U?

Comment: is it that (M+U)/U < W/U < V/U if and only if M<W<V and M is maximal so done?

Comment: @Abdul Razat: Sorry for my bad English. "Let $M$ runs..." - I mean "Denote by $M$ a maximal submodule".

Comment: @Abdul Razat: If $(M+U)/U < W/U < V/U$ then $W>M+U$, so either $W=M$ (if $M>U$) or $W=V$.